# Cakephp Nginx Ajenti config GUI

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx, ubuntu-13.10

Hello I am looking for further information about [Ajenti V](http://ajenti.org) and CakePHP on Ubuntu 13.10 server.

I just installed a new server with an admin interface (Ajenti V) to a client request, but I am worried for configuer with this GUI CakePHP web application.

In nomral time simple rules in [Nginx configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#pretty-urls-on-nginx) file dedicated enough to run CakePHP.

Could you provide me details correctly to setup a website on Ajenti with CakePHP from the GUI ?

Comment: you will need to talk to your host provider regarding to your issue. If you got any normal error during the configuration then you can ask community

Comment: Hi @IsaacRajaei, i am administrator of my server, but i would like my customer can configure itself in the future on its websites Ajenti GUI.

Comment: Hi @AD7six,The configuration of my server is perfect :). The tag Ajenti it does not exist on stackoverflow, the question is not simple even Google has no answer. The comunity of Ajenti is nonexistent so to have this is not simple answers, my question is simply due to the setting Ajenti with CakePHP Framework.

Comment: too bad, because we have "Feedback & support" all over both our website and panel itself, which point to http://support.ajenti.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this Ajenti-V+PHP tutorial: http://support.ajenti.org/topic/353409-setting-up-a-php-website-with-ajenti-v-wordpress-example/

As for the rewrite rule, you need to add this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

to "Custom Configuration" of your website

Comment: This is the only part of config that has to be manually added with Ajenti V; other parts of config from the docs will be auto-generated.

Comment: Nginx will match to this location, and unless $uri is an existing file, processing will continue to the ~ \.php location